# Why does my single-section, 2-group compositional layout only use the sizing of the first group in the section?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I am trying to create a compositional layout comprised of a group of 2 items, plus another group of 1 item. I would like each group to occupy the full screen width, and page-scroll between them. So the 2 items in the first group (Items A) would each occupy 50% of the screen width, and the 1 item (Item B) in the second group would occupy 100% of the screen width. I have the collection view pinned to the left and right edges of its superview, which occupies the entire screen.

A textual diagram would appear something like this:

```
[Item A][Item A]|[    Item B    ]
```

Where "|" denotes the edge of the screen. So depending on scroll position, either both Items A will be visible, or Item B will be visible. Item A and Item B should never be visible at the same time after scrolling has ended.

I am using the following code for my compositional layout:

```
UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionIndex, layoutEnvironment in
    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))

    let planItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.5), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
    let planItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: planItemSize)
    let planGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: planItem, count: 2)

    let formItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: groupSize)
    let formGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: formItem, count: 1)

    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [planGroup, formGroup])
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPaging
    return section
}
```

The above code is resulting in a layout that looks like this:

```
[Item A][Item A]|[Item B]
```

It is nearly correct except that Item B is being sized at 50% width of the screen instead of 100%. I can't figure out what's wrong with the layout, but it appears to be using `planItemSize` for all items, instead of just for Items A. How do I get Item B to be sized at 100% the screen width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we could do this very easily with a Horizontal Flow Layout, `.isPagingEnabled = true`, and implementing `sizeForItemAt`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let w: CGFloat = collectionView.frame.width
    let h: CGFloat = collectionView.frame.height

    if indexPath.item % 3 == 2 {
        return .init(width: w, height: h)
    }
    
    return .init(width: w * 0.5, height: h)
    
}
```

and we're done :)

However, since you're asking about `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`, let's look at that.

When working with **items**, **groups** and **sub-groups**, `.fractionalWidth()` and `.fractionalHeight()` is *relative to the **parent***.

Since we're using `100%` for all heights in this layout, we'll focus on widths.

For a "basic" layout, `.fractionalWidth(1.0)` will be 100% of the width of the collection view.

Using `.fractionalWidth(0.5)` will, of course, be 50% of the width of the collection view.

When we put an items in a **group**, the `count:` affects the size and the item width is (apparently) ignored.

So, if we set a group to `.fractionalWidth(1.0)` (100% of the width of the collection view), and set count to 4:

```
let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 4)
let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
return section
```

We'll get this (red outline is collection view frame):

[image]

We can change `itemSize` `.fractionalWidth(1.0)` to `0.1`, `0.5`, `2.0`, etc... it doesn't change the layout.

---

That said, in your current code, you are setting ***both*** `planGroup` and `formGroup` to `100%` width of their parent - `group` - which is **also** `100%` of the width of the collection view.

So, only the *first* group fits, and the second group is never used.

Let's fix that (I'm going to change `group` to `mainGroup` to make it easier to talk about).

What we can do instead is set `planGroup` to `.fractionalWidth(0.5)` and `formGroup` to `.fractionalWidth(0.5)` ... and we'll get close:

[image]

But - how do we get two items to fill the collection view, followed by one item, followed by two items, etc?

We can set the `mainGroup` width to **200%** of the collection view width:

[image]

Now we get the desired "pattern." Note that we will want to use `.paging` instead of `.groupPaging` because we want to page by collection view Width:

[image]

[image]

Here is a modified version of your code - you should be able to drop it right in as a replacement:

```
    UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
        (sectionIndex: Int, layoutEnvironment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
        
        // main group size is TWICE as wide as the collection view
        let mainGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(2.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
        
        // sub-groups
        //  width is Percentage-of-Parent
        //  so if each sub-group is one-half the width of the main group
        //  each will be the Full width of the collection view
        let planGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.5), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
        let formGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.5), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
        
        // because we're putting TWO planItems in planGroup
        //  CompositionLayout will use 50% of planGroup width for each item
        //  so planItemSize width is ignored
        let planItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
        let planItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: planItemSize)
        let planGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: planGroupSize, subitem: planItem, count: 2)
        
        // because we're putting ONE formItem in formGroup
        //  CompositionLayout will use 100% of formGroup width
        //  so formItemSize width is ignored
        let formItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
        let formItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: formItemSize)
        let formGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: formGroupSize, subitem: formItem, count: 1)
        
        let mainGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: mainGroupSize, subitems: [planGroup, formGroup])
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: mainGroup)
        
        // use .paging instead of .groupPaging
        //  because we want to page by collection view Width
        section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .paging
        
        return section
        
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a fantastic answer. I was admittedly quite frustrated with this particular issue because I've made significantly more complex compositional layouts and yet couldn't get this seemingly simple one to work. Your comprehensive explanation has shown that there are some concepts that I didn't correctly understand which led to this issue.

Comment: Please Answer This question If you know the answer. suggest my any other solution to solve this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78146212/how-can-i-ensure-uniform-item-widths-across-a-group-of-same-column-in-a-table-in)